# remote debug with xdebug on centos 6.4

Tags: centos, php, xdebug

I try remote debug php application with phpstorm. I use centos 6.4, php5.3 and apache 2.2 on vmware virtual machine, and phpstorm with firefox on real ubuntu. 
xdebug is really installed:

```
Installed Packages
Name        : php-pecl-xdebug
Arch        : i686
Version     : 2.1.4
Release     : 1.el6
Size        : 580 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : PECL package for debugging PHP scripts
URL         : http://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug
License     : PHP
```

And phpinfo confirm this too:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

When i run script (simple hello world) from console via ssh my script is stopped, i get connection to mu ide from xdebug and xdebug write info in own log.
But when i run script from browsen - is has no effect, even in xdebug log.
I try use firefox extension to start debug session, i try use xdebug.remote_autostart=1 option, tru turn off iptables in centos, but no effect too. 
What i do wrong?
xdebug config:

```
; Enable xdebug extension module
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so
;xdebug.remote_host=10.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.remote_mode=req
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
;xdebug.remote_autostart=1
;xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

Answer (score 6):

Oh my god, problem solved. It's all selinux.

setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1, nttpd restart - and phpstorm get connection from xdebug.

Comment: Hi, would you please elaborate more on your answer? I'm trying to achieve the same but hasn't been able so far. Thanks

Comment: You have same problem? xdebug can get connection from console script, but can't get when script executed by http server? And you work in redhat/centos/fedora (system with selinux)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. My VM server uses Centos 7 and my host is OS X

Comment: Well, all my actions - is two commands from VM console:

setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1

and then

service httpd restart

Is this commands executed without errors?

Answer (score 0):

etc/selinux/config change

- This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
- SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
- enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
- permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
- disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
  SELINUX=enforcing
- SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
- targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
- minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are
  protected.
- mls - Multi Level Security protection.

SELINUXTYPE=targeted

to

- This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
- SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
- enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
- permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
- disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.

SELINUX=disabled

- SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
- targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
- minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are 
  protected.
- mls - Multi Level Security protection.

SELINUXTYPE=targeted